# scipy splprep suppress warnings not caught by "quiet"

Tags: python, scipy

Does anyone know if it is possible to suppress the following fitpack warning that is thrown up by python's scipy.interpolate.splprep?

The warning is not a problem in terms of my code and output - but it does pollute my stderr / stdout output - heavily in my case.

Setting quite=1 in splprep does not suppress this output. 
scipy version 0.11.0

3:["""\
    The maximal number of iterations (20) allowed for finding smoothing
    spline with fp=s has been reached. Probably causes: s too small.
    (abs(fp-s)/s>0.001)""",ValueError]

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been [fixed](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/4003) in scipy master, the fix should be available in scipy 0.15.